# Strange safari rendering issues, and low performance on other browsers

Tags: html, css, performance, web, rendering

I'm in the middle of development of a [website](http://freeplayenergy.com.gridhosted.co.uk), however I cannot work out what is causing this plethora of issues.

In Safari on OS X (7.0.6 on 10.9.4), random elements will disappear and reappear and hovering over the drop down menu, or a button, they suddenly re-appear. It is very strange and erratic.

In Chrome (v36.0.1985.143) and Firefox (v31.0) the scrolling performance is poor, but no rendering issue.

All onscroll events are clean. I've tried tweaking with just about everything and gotten nowhere.

If anybody can work this out, I'll be greatly appreciative.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any scrolling performance issue on chrome or firefox, but I noticed Safari rendering glitches.

When you force reflow, all your sections are displaying again. Try to add a `backface-visibility:hidden;` on your `.section` class.

**Edit:**

Your `#background-area` is fixed and doesn't have any `z-index`. Put it to `z-index: -1;` to keep it in the back.

Comment: You're welcome, I also saw that your footer is animated with a bottom value. It would be much better to animate a translate3d value.

Comment: OK, I did not code that element, another dev did. I will change it though. I do remember seeing somewhere that translations were better performers than the top/left/right/bottom properties.

Comment: Indeed. CSS transformation generally perform better than top left positionning. Moreover, transform3d is computed on the GPU, which results in smooth and antialiased transformations.