# Safari renders some of my text garbled and distorted; selecting the text cleans it up a bit

Tags: safari, rendering, repaint

This text *usually* looks fine when the page loads. This distortion usually happens when I open a modal, enter a code that requests data from an API, and close the modal after a successful response. The retrieval of this code will change the price, but Safari doesn’t update the text until I interact with it, like selecting it.

The first price you see here ($10,578.30) is the old price. Safari just hadn’t repainted that text.

[image]

What the hell is happening here??

- Safari 12.0
- macOS 10.13.6 High Sierra

Comment: did you try turning it off and on again?

Comment: Yeah. And I tried blowing on it.

Comment: May you attach the HTML & JavaScript code of this part? maybe the problem is there.

Comment: Looks like a rendering bug in the browser to me. It doesn't recognise, that it needs to redraw the area until you trigger another visual change to the area by selecting it.
[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25400909/strange-safari-rendering-issues-and-low-performance-on-other-browsers) odd behavior was able to be fixed with CSS, so maybe try playing with some properties. Code for reproduction would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `jquery` to force a redraw of the buggy element.
Assuming that your buggy element have : `theBuggyElement` class name

Put this somewhere in the code:

```
$.fn.redraw = function(){
  $(this).each(function(){
    var redraw = this.offsetHeight;
  });
};
```

Then use this after update:

```
$('.theBuggyElement').redraw();
```

Comment: The content is already being redrawn several times as other values are changing. Unfortunately this didn’t resolve the issue.